# Vite did not Work Properly loading asset on laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Vite didnt load asset properly on my laravel 9 project. i've been facing this problem when using laravel 9 with Vite. first when i install laravel breeze i though the breeze is the problem, but now i try using jetstream it has the same issue. please see the screenshot below. can someone help me ?
[image: Jetstream Auth Pages]

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to run the Vite server using `npm run dev`. That will also take  care of hot reloading

Answer (score 0):

I run "npm run dev" command by mistake. And website is started using dev url. I searched for a solution but never found. I found solution myself. You need to delete "hot" file in your public folder on your hosting.

In you hosting go to "public" path and delete named "hot" file.